# What is the probability of winning the prize

Tags: statistics

In a lottery game, a machine has 48 balls marked with numbers from 1-48 and six of them are taken out at random. A player picks six of these numbers, trying to match the six balls that come out of the machine in any order. If exactly 4 of those 6 numbers match those drawn, the player wins third prize. What is the probability of winning this prize?

How would I solve this problem?

Comment: So I think you have a trial that has a probability of success of $p=\frac{6}{48}$. This trial is repeated $6$ times. What is the probability that there are exactly four successes among these $6$ trials?

Comment: I don't know? please help

Comment: Hint: Binomial distribution.

Comment: Can you solve this: there are $48$ marbles in a bag. Exactly $6$ of them are green. If you pick out (without replacement) $6$ balls then what is the probability that exactly $4$ of them are green? (hypergeometric distribution).

Comment: @MattiP. I would rather think it is hypergeometric. I don't think the machine gets the balls back.

Comment: @drhab Ah, good point. I agree.

Comment: binomcdf(48,6/48,4) = .2671923158 is that the right answer??

Answer (score 1):

There are $\ {6\choose 4}\ $ subsets of the player's $6$ cards which could be the one exactly matched, and the matching set could occur in any of $\ {6\choose 4}\ $ sets of positions of the $6$-ball draw.  There are thus $\ {6\choose 4}^2\ $ different ways in which the match could occur, each with the same probability of
$$
\frac{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot42\cdot41}{48\cdot47\cdot46\cdot45\cdot44\cdot43}\ .
$$
Thus, the probability of such an exact match occurring is
$$
{6\choose 4}^2\frac{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot42\cdot41}{48\cdot47\cdot46\cdot45\cdot44\cdot43}=\frac{4305}{4090504}\approx0.00105
$$